# Automate download of google-services.json for Android

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to automate downloading the google-services.json configuration file for a Firebase app?

I'm using Firebase and looking for a way to automate a new application incl. Crashlytics.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest), specifically [projects.androidApps.getConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps/getConfig).